# Understanding state in jest tests that use spyOn

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Suppose that I have a test file `foo.test.ts` that looks like this:

```
describe("foo", function() {
  let myMock;

  beforeAll(function() {
    myMock = jest.spyOn(someObject, "someMethod");
  });

  test("my test", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      myMock.mockReturnValue("someValue");
    });
    ...
  });

  afterAll(function() {
    myMock.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

I'm using this pattern because I've seen it recommended in other StackOverflow answers. I wish to understand how Jest works though.

Do I really need to store the mock in a variable, or can I do this?

```
describe("foo", function() {
  test("my test", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      jest.spyOn(someObject, "someMethod").mockReturnValueOnce("someValue");
    });
    ...
  });
});
```

Notice that I'm using `mockReturnValueOnce` instead of `mockReturnValue`.

I ran both implementations and they work fine, but I wonder whether I can say that they are equivalent? Will the "someMethod" function, part of "someObject", not be retained as a mock across other tests from other files?

Comment: I learnt how to use jest from this gh repo: https://github.com/sapegin/jest-cheat-sheet#mock-object-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`jest.spyOn()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) returns a jest [`mock function`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api) and you want to store the returned mock function in a variable so that you can make assertions.

If you don't store the mock function returned by `jest.mock()`, then how will you make assertions? All the methods, provided by jest, that can be called on a mock function, can't be called without having a reference to the mock function.

If you just want to mock a return value and not make any assertions on the mocked function, then you don't need to save the reference. Generally, when you mock a function, you want to make assertions like how many times it was called, what arguments it was called with, etc.

> Will the "someMethod" function, part of "someObject", not be retained
> as a mock across other tests from other files?

`someMethod` will only be mocked in the test file where you mock it. It won't affect the other test files.

Comment: Hmm, I think I shouldn't use `spyOn` then. I don't want to make assertions on the mocked function (like how many times it had been called). I simply want to mock its return value once, because other functions I want to test depend on this return value.

Comment: _"I simply want to mock its return value once"_ - in that case, you don't need to save the reference to a mock function and your second code example will work fine.